# UserForm click checkbox to fill an offset from a filled cell VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need a checkbox to, once clicked, fill in a value at an offset of the last client name (the last filled cell starting from `B3`). There's a submit button that fills in client name and calculates a value in tons. The idea is that after the client name is filled in and the tons calculated, the checkbox should write the ton value in the appropriate offset cell. The userform then moves the client and ton value to the next available empty cell, this is why I want to base the checkbox from the last client name. I can't make the userform check the last empty cell and use the checkbox to fill it because sometimes the cell above will be empty, depending on the material bought.

[image]

Here's my code (trying to make the offset use the cell check method for the clients)

```
Private Sub CHKTALCO_Click()
  Dim T As Long

  Sheets("Sales").Activate
  ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Activate

  Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(T, 1)) = False
    T = T + 1
  Loop

  If CHKTALCO.Value = 1 Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(T, 1).Value = TBTONS.Value
  End If
End Sub
```

I've been learning VBA as I go so explanations will be very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

To find the last used row in any particular column, I use this:

```
lastRow = YourSheet.Cells(Yoursheet.Rows.Count, YourColumn).End(xlUp).Row
```

You could replace your subroutine with something like this:

```
Private Sub CHKTALCO_Click()

    dim lastRow as long
    dim sht As Worksheet

    set sht = Worksheets("Sales")

    lastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count,"B").End(xlUp).Row

    If CHKTALCO.Value = 1 Then
        sht.Cells(lastRow, 3).Value = TBTONS.Value
    End If

End Sub
```

Note: It's faster to *not* use `.Activate` as it isn't necessary.

Comment: First, thanks for the response Porcupine. Second, I have tried the last rows check but since there are pre-filled cells on the form then the userform would write all the way at the bottom. That's why I use active cell to find `B3` and move down. Also for some reason when I input this row check code the form is not writing anything, which is even odder.